# Tag creation request

Tags: discussion, status-declined

I have a question about my Super User post: [`vim | less` breaks things](https://superuser.com/questions/1469564/vim-less-breaks-things)
*(autogenerated header)*

May the community please create the following tags:

- bug
- less

---

Tag *#discussion* is included because it is the required tag that I thing applies the most.

Answer (score 5):

"bug" would be a meta-tag, i.e. a tag that is meaningless on its own or is only useful in conjunction with other more descriptive tags. We do not create such tags and in fact we [actively hunt and remove them](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=meta%20tag).

The [less](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/less) tag already exists on the main site and does not need to be created.

Comment: Well, rethinking _#bug_, maybe it is a meta tag... but I typed less in the tag box and it said no results. I will check again...